# How to create new Entity Object with autoincremented field in Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

How can I initialize a new entity object in Room assuming that one of its fields is autoincremented?

Example code:

```
@Entity
data class MyEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val id: Int,
        val title: String,
)
```

Dao:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertEntity(myEntity: MyEntity): Long
```

Repository:

```
...
//#1
val newEntity = MyEntity(title = "mytitle")

database.entityDao().insertEntity(newEntity)
```

Below #1 compiler throws an error that id value has not been provided. How can I initialize the object presented below #1 using the auto-incrementation feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare it as `nullable`, then your insertion snippet works perfectly:

```
@Entity
data class MyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int? = null,
    val title: String,
)
```

Then:

```
val newEntity = MyEntity(title = "mytitle")
database.entityDao().insertEntity(newEntity)
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of you (and @sergiy tikhonov) are correct. I will mark your answer as approved because you was first.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value of the autoincremeted field to 0.

```
@Entity
data class MyEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val id: Int = 0,
        val title: String,
)
```

OR

each time to set it through constructor:

```
val newEntity = MyEntity(id = 0, title = "mytitle")
```